# How to Animated Align?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

[image]

This is my bottom navigation bar and I want animate that white dot when I am    click bar item.
I am using animatedAlign Widget but problem is I can't find accurate alignment position.
if anyone know solution please share

Comment: Can you include your current snippet

Comment: I don't know what are you saying

Comment: The current code of this UI

Comment: that's not working

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use `AnimatedPositioned` instead of  `AnimatedAlign` to me. For left position

You can use this logic for left position

```dart
  double getLeft(width) {
    final double singleTabSpace = width / tabLength;
    // current tab end - half of tab width - half while circle
    return (singleTabSpace * (activeIndex + 1)) -
        (singleTabSpace / 2) -
        (10 / 2);
  }
```

Play with this widget

```dart
class ParentW extends StatefulWidget {
  ParentW({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ParentW> createState() => _ParentWState();
}

class _ParentWState extends State<ParentW> {
  int activeIndex = 0;

  int tabLength = 5;

  double getLeft(width) {
    final double singleTabSpace = width / tabLength;
    // current tab end - half of tab width - half while circle
    return (singleTabSpace * (activeIndex + 1)) -
        (singleTabSpace / 2) -
        (10 / 2);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: TSA(),
      body: Column(
        children: [],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: kToolbarHeight,
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) => Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: List.generate(
                    tabLength,
                    (index) => IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          activeIndex = index;
                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              AnimatedPositioned(
                bottom: 5,
                left: getLeft(constraints.maxWidth),
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                child: Container(
                  width: 10,
                  height: 10,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: test the widget and hope this the thing you wanted, using animated align is easy while you like to deal with static value, like moving between two position